# Find n in sum that results in a number $aaa$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

Lets say that we have the sum $1+2+3+\ldots+n$ where $n$ is a positive natural number and that this sum should equal a three digit number in which all the digits are the same, for example $111, 222,$ and so on.

What would be the best way to find the $n$ that would result in such a number? I guess you could solve $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=111x$ but that seems a bit too hard.

From trial and error we know that the only solution is $n=36$ which gives $666$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2=111x$ implies $37$ divides $n$ or $n+1$

Comment: can the sum be a four or higher digit number?

Comment: @vidyarthi:  OP said the sum should equal a three digit number

Comment: Just found that another number is 221

Comment: @HarshitGupta:  $n=221$ satisfies $\dfrac {n(n+1)}2=111x$, but with $x=221>9$

Comment: Interestingly there doesn't seem to be a solution if the total is a four-digit number with all the same digits.

Comment: @hypergeometric:  maybe not so surprising — if there are about $100$ $4$-digit triangular numbers and $9$ of about $9000$ $4$-digit numbers are of the form $xxxx$ then (assuming randomness/independence) the probability that no triangular number is of the form $xxxx$ is about $\left(1-\dfrac1{1000}\right)^{100}\approx1-\dfrac1{10}=90\%$

Comment: yeah but by that same logic over a 73% chance that no three digit example existed.

Answer (score 5):

Since $111=3\times37, \dfrac{n(n+1)}2=111x$ implies $37$ divides $n$ or $n+1$,

so we have to try only $n=36$ and $n=37$,

because, for $n\ge2\times37-1,$ $\dfrac {n(n+1)}2$ has more than $3$ digits.

Comment: Cool! That was what I was thinking also but couldn't figure out if there was another way. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, you don't even have to try $n=37$.  It fails to allow the required factor of $3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\frac {n(n+1)}2&=111m\qquad (m=1,2,3,\cdots,9)\\
n^2+n-222m&=0\\
n&=\frac {-1\pm \sqrt{1+888m}}2\end{align}$$
Check for values of $m$ where $(1+888m)$ is a perfect square of an odd number.

The only solution is $m=6$, where $\sqrt{1+888m}=73$. This gives 
$$n=\frac {-1\pm 73}2=36\qquad (n>0)$$

Comment: I think you meant $73$ where you typed $72$

Comment: Typo corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I still maintain that people who downvote should be required to include a reason for downvoting, with the option not to identify themselves. That will increase the usefulness of this forum.